# Is there any smaller SQLite library that support read contain of database?

Tags: sqlite

I want to build a small application (on Windows), one of function is read the SQLite database (SELECT query). I just need to select some columns from table, no need to update/insert/delete ... 

Of course, SQLite is an open source software, then I can get source code easily. Actually I did it, but it's to big because it support full APIs. All I need are just some APIs: sqlite3_open, sqlite3_close, sqlite3_get_table, sqlite3_free_table. 

I tried to porting source code to smaller lib, but the data structure and API too complex ...

Please let me know if you know the other library (smaller and simpler) or some one did it before can help with share some idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what kind of an environment, especially windows, requires to fine tune the size of a used library? I can think of embedded devices, but on windows this puzzles me.